# Checking if a label I click, is a part of a pattern of labels

Tags: c#, list, design-patterns, click, label

I am making a game about remembering a pattern of labels, that show up by them changing colors. The user then has to click the labels showed, in the correct order.

After the pattern has been randomly chosen, it goes into a list called the 'pattern'. My problem here is; how do I make it so that my label_Click event handler can be used to check if the correct label has been clicked for the entire list, in the correct order. Sorry that my code is clumsy and without comments, I have just started programming.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace Spil
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        Label[] labelArray;
        int turn = 1;
        int lives = 3;
        List<Label> pattern = new List<Label>();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            labelArray = new Label[] { label1, label2, label3, label4, label5, label6, label7, label8, label9 };
        }

        private void DisplayOrder()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < labelArray.Length; i++)
            {
                labelArray[i].BackColor = Color.Blue;
                labelArray[i].Click += label_Click;
            }

            for (int i = -2; i < turn; i++)
            {
                int chosenNumber = rnd.Next(0, 9);
                labelArray[chosenNumber].BackColor = Color.Green;
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                labelArray[chosenNumber].BackColor = Color.Blue;
                pattern.Add(labelArray[chosenNumber]);
            }
        }

        private void label_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Label clickedLabel = sender as Label;
        }

        private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Timers.Timer t = new System.Timers.Timer(100);

            t.Elapsed += t_Elapsed;

            t.Start();
        }

        void t_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            ((System.Timers.Timer)sender).Stop();

            DisplayOrder();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to keep track of the turn, so you know what index in `pattern` to look for when the user clicks a label, i.e. for the first click/turn, you can check if `pattern[0] == clickedLabel`. If it is the user was right and you can increment the index to 1, because that is the next label you expect to be clicked.

Comment: I have tried this, but the only way I made it work (sort of) was to have a for loop inside the Label_Clicked eventhandler itself, instead of having it around it. This caused my code to only make the user click once, and then it would check through the list and try to match for every index that for loop would do, for that one click. Is there a way I can loop the click eventhandler, so that the user can click for each time the for for loop loops?

Comment: I added an answer that shows how you can solve the parts that gave you trouble.

Comment: Your "continue with game" or "new game" question, is a different question than the current one. If an answer addresses your current question (checking if a clicked label is a part of a pattern), please mark it as the answer, so that this question can be removed from the "unanswered" list. For your new question: ask a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to keep track of matching user label clicks, you will need to keep track of the turn, so you know what index in pattern to look for when the user clicks a label.

So for the first click/turn, you can check if `pattern[0] == clickedLabel`. If it is the user was right and you can increment the index to 1, because that is the next label you expect to be clicked.

You can keep track of this by making some modifications to your code as shown below. **Note**: It only shows the modifications for keeping track of the user's tries, the rest of your original code remains untouched.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    // A user is allowed a maximum of 3 guesses per label.
    private const int MaxTries = 3;

    // The number of guesses for the current label.
    private int _triesOnCurrentLabel;

    // The number of labels guessed correctly so far.
    // This is also the index into the patterns list.
    private int _numberGuessedRight;

    // The game is over if the user guessed all labels
    // or used more than the maximum number of tries on a label.
    private bool _gameOver;

    // ... other stuff

    private void label_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label clickedLabel = sender as Label;
        if (!_gameOver)
        {
            if (pattern[_numberGuessedRight] == clickedLabel)
            {
                // The user guessed right.
                _triesOnCurrentLabel = 0; // reset, 3 tries for next label.
                _numberGuessedRight++;
                _gameOver = _numberGuessedRight == pattern.Count;
                if (_gameOver)
                {
                    // Show the user a message? "YOU WON"
                }
            }
            else if (++_triesOnCurrentLabel >= MaxTries)
            {
                // User used up all tries on the current label.
                _gameOver = true;
                // Show the user a message? "Game over YOU LOSER"
            }
        }
    }

    // ... the rest
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time I really appreaciate it.This looks awesome, but what if I want to have more turns, so that if the current pattern (containing 3 labels) is guessed, the 'turn' goes up and there now is a pattern of 4 labels. How do I make that loop which makes the code go up to the beggining (if you know what I mean). I have tried the GOTO command before, but I've also heard that you should awoid that at all cost.

Comment: @EsbenJuulDalsgaard You mean that you want to start a new game when it is "game over"?

Comment: Well sort of, the game does not need to have an end so to speak. You play and it get's harder and harder with more and more labels in each pattern, and you can only really fail, not win. You just go as far as you can.

Comment: Ok, that is a different question than the current one. Please "wrap up" this current one that provides you with a way to do what you asked. Next, ask your new question as a new question. Make sure, that you think about approaches that you could try yourself first.